# Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established when connecting to gRPC Service

Tags: node.js, grpc, google-cloud-run

I deployed a gRPC service to Cloud Run and was given a service url of the form:

```
https://customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app
```

I now attempted to connect to that service from localhost using the following code:

```
  let client = new customer_proto.Customer("dns:customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app:50051", grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
```

but all I keep getting back is the following error:

> Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established

What can I do differently to make this work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the implementation of `customer_proto.Customer` so it's not possible to provide a definitive answer.

<strike>It's **unlikely** that the method expects the endpoint to be prefixed `dns:`. I would expect it to want the Cloud Run service endpoint and, because gRPC doesn't have default ports, (and as I mentioned previously, Cloud Run maps services to) `:443` too, i.e.</strike>

`customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app:443`

A good tool that I use to test gRPC services is [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl). Postman is quite common for REST and now [supports gRPC](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/)

If your service support reflection, you can:

```bash
grpcurl customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app:443 list
```

Otherwise, you'll need to reference the service's proto file(s), the service and a method (possibly with data) to test:

```bash
grpcurl \
-proto {your-proto} \
customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app:443 \
{package}.{Service}/{MethodName}
```

You can confirm that the host is defined and responds with:

```bash
nslookup customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app

telnet customer-service-random-string-ue.a.run.app 443
```

Comment: The `dns:` prefix matches the [gRPC target naming convention](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md) so it is likely valid. In addition, gRPC does have a default port and it is 443 (also specified in that document).

Comment: @murgatroid99 I did not know about `dns:` and have not seen that used before, thanks!